# How to calculate unknown function in a equation analyticaly?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, code-review, code-request, resolve

I want value of u1 in terms of T1. How i will be abel to do this?

```
V5 = 0;
Q1 = 1.6021*10^(-19);
L1 = 0.57;
D1 = 0.032;
M1 = 18.01528;
A1 = 2*(Q1*(V1 - V5)/M1);
Solve[T1 - (Sqrt[u1^4 + A1] - u1)/(A1*D1) - L1/(Sqrt[u1^3 + A1])==0,{T1,u1}]
```

This is giving me the value of T1 but i need u1 in terms of T1. why this happening.

Comment: Look at the documentation of `Solve`.

Comment: @ Marius Ladegård Meyer Yes, Now i have edited the code, after seeing the documentation of Solve. My problem is that it is giving me the result in terms of u1, but i need the value of u1, in terms of T1.

Comment: Then put only `u1` as your variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vsol = V1 /. 
  NSolve[(Sqrt[u1^4 + A1] - u1)/(A1*D1) + L1/(Sqrt[u1^3 + A1]), 
    V1][[1]]

Plot[vsol, {u1, 0, .01}]
```

This is a case where I would recommend rescaling your units so you are not multiplying large numbers with small numbers and then adding and subracting them.

Or you could do something like this:

```
V5 = 0;
Q1 = Rationalize[1.6021*10^(-19), 10^(-20)];
L1 = Rationalize[0.57];
D1 = Rationalize[0.032];
M1 = Rationalize[18.01528];
A1 = 2*(Q1*(V1 - V5)/M1);
T1 = (Sqrt[u1^4 + A1] - u1)/(A1*D1) + L1/(Sqrt[u1^3 + A1]);

Solve[0 == (Sqrt[u1^4 + A1] - u1)/(A1*D1) + L1/(Sqrt[u1^3 + A1]), V1]
```